# Christoffel symbol for Schwarzschild metric

Tags: general-relativity, coordinate-systems, metric-tensor

I know that the christoffel (second kind) can be defined like this:

$$\Gamma^m_{ij} = \frac{1}{2} g^{mk}(\frac{\partial g_{ki}}{\partial U^j}+\frac{\partial g_{jk}}{\partial U^i}-\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial U^k})$$

but I don't know how $U^i$ is defined (specifically for the [Schwarzschild metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. $U^0 = t$, $U^1 = r$, $U^2 = \theta$, and $U^3 = \phi$ in the typical order with conventional coordinate labels in the Schwarzschild metric. Well, you can permute them any way you like, as long as you keep the metric tensor components consistent.

Comment: So in that case, I can just differentiate with respect to t, r theta and phi and get the christoffel symbol?

Comment: Yes, just remember the Einstein summation convention when doing so. To be clear: the Schwarzschild metric is diagonal, in $-+++$ convention $g_{00} = -(1-2M/r)$, ..., $g_{33} = r^2\sin^2\theta$, the contravariant components $g^{mk}$ can be found through matrix inverse (so in this particular case they're just straight inverses because of diagonality).

Comment: So $g^{00} = -1/(1-2M/r)$?

Comment: Yup. Diagonal metrics are nice that way.

Comment: One other thing, how would I calculate the partial derivative of $(2Gm/r-1)$ with respect to $t$? What is r(t)?

Comment: Since no components are dependent $t$, $\partial_t g_{ij} = 0$ for any $i,j$. Similarly $\partial_\phi g_{ij} = 0$, but not for $r$ or $\theta$. If you like, you can edit your question to show your attempt and people will try correct it if need be.

Comment: But $g^00 = 1/(2Gm/r-1), and r should depend on time, right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8708/discussion-between-stan-liou-and-user912)

Comment: @StanLiou I'm unable to chat on my phone, but I need help differentiating the metric elements.

Comment: Very well.It's a partial derivative. The metric components have no explicit $t$-dependence, so all $\partial_t(\ldots)$ are zero. You may be confusing this with the fact that most geodesic will have time-varying $r$, but the geometry is not dependent on the Schwarzschild $t$-coordinate at all. Edit: Rather, the $t$-dependence in the geodesics will come from the geodesic equation directly.

Comment: Okay, but what about with respect to $r$?

Comment: What about it? $\partial_r g_{00} = -2M/r^2$, $\ldots$, $\partial_r g_{33} = 2r\sin^2\theta$. You should be able to do the rest yourself. Edit: Like I said previously, if you edit it what you're getting into your question, people will be willing to check it and correct it if need be, as long as you're showing an attempt to do it yourself.

Comment: @Stan it would be good if you make an answer out of some of those earlier comments

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky alright, done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Schwarzschild metric is, in $-+++$ sign convention and units of $c = 1$ is
$$\mathrm{d}s^2 = -\left(1-\frac{2M}{r}\right)\mathrm{d}t^2 + \frac{\mathrm{d}r^2}{1-\frac{2M}{r}} + r^2\left(\mathrm{d}\theta^2 + \sin^2\theta\,\mathrm{d}\phi^2\right)\text{.}$$
We can index the coordinates arbitrarily, but let's take them in the typical order: $(U^0,U^1,U^2,U^3) = (t,r,\theta,\phi)$. In the metric, terms like $\mathrm{d}t^2$ are shorthand for the tensor product $\mathrm{d}t\otimes\mathrm{d}t$ and cross-terms like $\mathrm{d}t\,\mathrm{d}r$ for $\frac{1}{2}\left(\mathrm{d}t\otimes\mathrm{d}r+\mathrm{d}r\otimes\mathrm{d}t\right)$, since the metric must be symmetric. But we don't have any cross-terms, so the covariant metric components form a diagonal matrix:
$$g_{ij} = \begin{bmatrix}-\left(1-\frac{2M}{r}\right) &0 &0 &0\\
0&\left(1-\frac{2M}{r}\right)^{-1} &0&0\\0&0&r^2&0\\0&0&0&r^2\sin^2\theta\\
\end{bmatrix}\text{,}$$
while the contravariant matrix components $g^{ij}$ form the matrix inverse of the above, which in the case of diagonality just simplifies to $g^{ij} = 1/g_{ij}$ if $i = j$ and $g^{ij} = 0$ otherwise.

Write $_{,n}$ for the partial derivative with respect to $U^n$. Then the connection coefficients / Christoffel symbols
$$\Gamma^m_{ij} = \frac{1}{2}g^{mk}\left[g_{ki,j} + g_{kj,i} - g_{ij,k}\right]$$
simplify in the diagonal case to just
$$\Gamma^m_{ij} = \frac{1}{2}g^{mm}\left[g_{mi,j} + g_{mj,i} - g_{ij,m}\right]\text{,}$$
since terms with $m\neq k$ have $g^{mk} = 0$, and in the Schwarzschild case the metric components are independent of either $t$ or $\phi$, so:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
g_{ij,0} = \frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial t} = 0&\quad\text{and}\quad&
g_{ij,3} = \frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial \phi} = 0\text{.}
\end{eqnarray*}$$
Thus for the Schwarszchild case, any off-diagonal term is zero and all partials by  $t$ or $\phi$ are also zero. For example,
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\Gamma^\phi_{\theta\phi} = \Gamma^3_{23} &= \frac{1}{2}\underbrace{\left(r^2\sin^2\theta\right)^{-1}}_{g^{33}}\left(\underbrace{g_{32,3}}_0 + g_{33,2} - \underbrace{g_{23,3}}_0\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(r^2\sin^2\theta\right)^{-1}\underbrace{\left(r^2\cdot2\sin\theta\cos\theta\right)}_{\partial_\theta(r^2\sin^2\theta)}= \cot\theta\text{.}\end{eqnarray*}$$
$$\Gamma^\phi_{r\phi} = \Gamma^3_{13} = \ldots = r^{-1}\text{,}$$
and other than terms required by symmetry of lower indices ($\Gamma^\phi_{\phi\theta} = \Gamma^\phi_{\theta\phi}$, &c.), those are the only nonzero $\Gamma^\phi_{ij}$. You should be able to find the rest yourself.

P.S. There are alternative ways of finding the connection coefficients other than the formula you're using, usually from a Lagrangian, but for diagonal metrics this direct approach isn't that bad at all.

Comment: Out of curiosity, would [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deriving_the_Schwarzschild_solution#Calculating_the_Christoffel_symbols) give me the components that I'd need to calculate, or should I still check if they're nonzero myself (I noticed that the matrix for $k = 0$ has a bunch of terms that aren't 0).

Comment: I meant to say $m = 0$

Comment: I suggest you edit to include that you've also set Newton's constant to 1.